# What is the interface to implement to create "folders" like the "ZIP compressed folders" in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, winapi, explorer, windows-shell

I think there is a way to extend the Windows Shell to make (for example) other types of archives in the same vein of the support for ZIP-files "compressed folders".

I admit that the Shell Interface is pretty clear when you're familiar with the shell terminology, but really obtuse otherwise. My current guess would be `IShellFolder`, but I think this would be creating an extra folder at the same place as andin addition to the file, instead of providing special support for the file itself.

Therefore, what to implement?

Comment: I think it's a shell namespace extension. IShellFolder is just the interface that represents all shell containers (folders).

Comment: That is exactly what it is.  An ordinary SNE that opens a .zip file and represents its content as folders and files using standard shell interfaces, like `IShellFolder` and `IShellItem`, and PIDLs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no shell interface specifically intended for implementing compressed folders.  It is implemented as an ordinary **Shell Namespace Extension** that just happens to create/open a normal .zip file and represent its content to the Shell using PIDLs and standard shell interfaces like `IShellFolder`, `IShellItem`, `IDataObject`, `IEnumIDList`, etc.  The SNE even represents a .zip file itself as a subfolder within its parent folder, instead of as a file, so the Shell can traverse into the .zip file using the SNE's `IShellFolder` implementation like any other folder.  The Shell has no concept that it is accessing a .zip file, it is just another Shell item whose characteristics tell the Shell how to work with it.  The SNE's implementation handles the details of accessing/updating the .zip file instead of the file system.

There is a whole section of MSDN that describes has to create Shell Namespace Extensions, including:

[Windows Shell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773177.aspx)

[Creating Shell Data Source Objects and Extending the Shell Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff521656.aspx)

[Creating Shell Extension Handlers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144067.aspx)

[Implementing the Basic Folder Object Interfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144093.aspx)

Comment: Isn't there a semantic overload on the word "extension" there? I may be wrong, but "extension handlers" seem to be about filepath extensions whereas "namespace extension" seems to be about extending the namespace.